# How to add Junit 5 library in eclipse juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit5, eclipse-juno

I know juno is old version. but is it possible to add any plugin to use junit 5? adding maven dependencies org.junit.jupiter will solve this issue?

Comment: JUnit 5 support was not added until Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) which is more than 5 years newer than Juno (but still old). It is very unlikely that anyone has back ported support to Juno.

Comment: If i add junit 5 dependecies in my spring boot project for test, will it work, is it possible to run junit 5 testcase in juno?